# How do I access this PHP variable (object->array->object)?

Tags: php, date, datetime, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
Foo_Transaction Object (
    [_attributes] => Array (
            [id] => abcdefg
            [orderId] => 
            [createdAt] => DateTime Object (
                    [date] => 2015-03-05 18:57:48.000000
                )
```

I can access `id` with `$result->transaction->id` just fine.

However, trying to access the `date` data with `$result->transaction->createdAt->date` returns NULL. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object so you need to use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get that date value as a string:

```
echo $result->transaction->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `createdAt` is a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) PHP object. To get this date as a string:

```
$result->transaction->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

See the documentation of the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for the accepted date formatting parameters.